Как обработать нажатие по button в tkinter
Приложение, в котором при нажатии на Button и правильной комбинации цифр закрывается одно приложение и открывается другое.
Не пойму как сделать обработчик кнопки

    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    
    def check_combination():
        entered_code = entry.get()
        if entered_code == "1234":
            root.destroy()
            open_new_window()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "Неправильная комбинация")
    
    def open_new_window():
        new_window = tk.Tk()
        new_window.title("Новое окно")
        new_window.geometry("300x200")
        tk.Label(new_window, text="Добро пожаловать в новое окно!").pack(pady=20)
        new_window.mainloop()
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Введите комбинацию")
    root.geometry("300x200")
    
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack(pady=20)
    
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Проверить", command=check_combination)
    button.pack(pady=10)
    
    root.mainloop()

Вот как создать приложение на Tkinter: определяешь функцию для проверки комбинации и нужных действий, создаёшь окно с полем ввода и кнопкой, связываешь кнопку с функцией через command, и запускаешь основной цикл с root.mainloop().
